# Google Translate API: Transliterated Input

Tags: node.js, google-translate, google-cloud-translate

We are currently developing an application which uses the Google Translate API. For that we use the Cloud Translate Library for Node.js.

This works until the **input** text is transliterated (e.g. from Cyrillic -> Latin).
A translation of the russian sentence "Я хочу поговорить с сотрудником." to another language works fine but when we use the latin transliteration "YA khochu pogovorit' s sotrudnikom." the Translation API just returns the input text (which is equivalent to not translated at all).

This is what our code looks:

```
this.googleTranslate = new TranslationServiceClient();

...

private static performOnlineTranslation(text: string, isoFrom: string, isoTo: string, callback: Function) {
        const request = {
            parent: `projects/xxx/locations/global`,
            contents: [text],
            mimeType: 'text/plain',
            sourceLanguageCode: isoFrom,
            targetLanguageCode: isoTo,
        };

        this.googleTranslate.translateText(request)
            .then((response: any[]) => {
                let trans = response[0].translations[0].translatedText;
                callback(trans);
            });
    }
```

We've stumbled across some solutions for modifying the **target** language transliteration by adding an '-Latn' to the language code but even this doesn't work for our example.

When using the online translation tool Google even offers the transliterated text and is also able to 'understand' transliterated **input**.

[image: Example Sceenshot]

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!